# Pyinstaller - unable to compile

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, openwrt

I am trying to use Pyinstaller to turn the below python script into a standalone, executable file in OpenWRT. However, I got the error message. Could anyone give me some hint on how to solve it? Thanks!!

```
root@mylinkit:/usr# cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#coding:utf-8
print('Hello World!')
```

---

```
root@mylinkit:/usr# pyinstaller test.py
2948 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
2950 INFO: Python: 2.7.9
2964 INFO: Platform: Linux-3.18.23-mips-with-glibc2.0
2971 INFO: wrote /usr/test.spec
3019 INFO: UPX is not available.
3041 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/usr', '/usr']
3045 INFO: checking Analysis
3048 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
3050 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
3106 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
6523 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')
 ()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, 
in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, 
in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), 
kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 373, in assemble
    redirects=self.binding_redirects)[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", 
line 227, in Dependencies
    for lib, npth in selectImports(pth, xtrapath):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", 
line 500, in selectImports
    dlls = getImports(pth)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", 
line 736, in getImports
    return _getImports_ldd(pth)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", 
line 571, in _getImports_ldd
    for line in compat.exec_command('ldd', pth).splitlines():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 350, 
in exec_command
    out = subprocess.Popen(cmdargs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
**kwargs).communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
root@mylinkit:/usr#
```

Comment: from the logs, it looks like "ldd" is missing in the router. Include the dev tools and then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: After manually installing ldd, the problem of "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" is solved..

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you like it.

Comment: I want to, but I cannot find the vote-up icon as described in the link below (could you show me how to up-vote)? http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up